# How can I destroy the selectize and unbind select box from it

Tags: selectize.js

I tried the following to destroy selectize:

```
$("#level1").selectize.destroy();
```

However it gives the **error**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize.destroy is not a function
```

I also tried:

```
$("#level1")[0].selectize.destroy();
```

It gives **error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: selectize is not defined
```

**How can i successfuly destroy the selectize?**
   Please suggest.

Comment: does `$("#level1")[0]` return an HTML select element? If yes, then you might be trying to destroy the selectize even before it is getting initialized!

Comment: `if($('#level1').size() > 0)
      $('#level1')[0].selectize.destroy()`

Comment: @Jeets Did you figure out solution to this problem after 2 years maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use selectize as a function to apply on your node before trying to destroy anything.

```
    var select = filtersDiv.find('class_of_your_select');

    var selectized = select.selectize();

    var control = selectized[0].selectize;

    control.destroy()
```

Note that I generally save all instances of the "control" variable in a list.

This allows me not to have to find them again in the DOM. Instead I can work on them directly.

Comment: @sonic I suggest you ask him from the comment section of his own question instead of my answer to successfully ping him